# SQL Server Update using WHERE and LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-like

I have this code that doesnt seem to work with the REPLACE. Am I missing something here

```
UPDATE EMIR
SET Series = CL.Underlying_Security_Name
FROM EMIR e
INNER JOIN CALYPSO cl
    ON e.Internal_ID = cl.Trade_ID
    AND e.Internal_ID_Type = 'CL'
    WHERE cl.Underlying_Security_Name like 'CMBX.NA.%'REPLACE((SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Underlying_Security_Name,'CMBX.NA.',''),CHARINDEX('.',REPLACE(Underlying_Security_Name,'CMBX.NA.',''))+1,2)),'.',''))
```

Comment: Think you need to concatenate your like with a +

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. How many records are updated? Are they the correct ones? Do you have a syntax error?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Igor  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PostProcessEMIRForFindandReplaceEMIRFields, Line 63
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.

Comment: Then you need to use string concatenation (as mentioned by @ste-fu). Use `+` to concatenate strings. As `replace` returns a string you need to concatenate it to the other strings around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bigger problem.  You need to `update` the *alias* defined in the `FROM` clause, not the table.

It is possible that your problem with the `replace()` needing a string concatenation:

```
UPDATE e
    SET Series = CL.Underlying_Security_Name
FROM EMIR e INNER JOIN
     CALYPSO cl
     ON e.Internal_ID = cl.Trade_ID AND e.Internal_ID_Type = 'CL'
WHERE cl.Underlying_Security_Name like 'CMBX.NA.%' + REPLACE((SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Underlying_Security_Name,'CMBX.NA.',''), CHARINDEX('.', REPLACE(Underlying_Security_Name,'CMBX.NA.',''))+1,2)),'.',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE emir
    SET Series = (select CL.Underlying_Security_Name
FROM EMIR e, 
     CALYPSO cl
     Where
 e.Internal_ID(+)  = cl.Trade_ID AND e.Internal_ID_Type = 'CL'
And cl.Underlying_Security_Name like 'CMBX.NA.%'REPLACE((SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Underlying_Security_Name,'CMBX.NA.',''),CHARINDEX('.',REPLACE(Underlying_Security_Name,'CMBX.NA.',''))+1,2)),'.',''))
```

Not sure about replace but modify the rest code as above